# Post API request failing when deployed in server's. Locally working

Tags: node.js, xml, rest, server, http-post

Our rest API is a Node.js. There are few large data requests like 50 -100mb of data. So when I do post request locally i was able to get data. But when I deploy in apache servers and try to post then I get could not get any response within a minute. The time usually takes to fetch that huge data is a minimum of 4 mins. But on apache servers, it fails below minute and instances start restarting. I thought it was js `heap out of memory` so in package JSON I updated `node --max_old_space_size=8092 --stack-size=85500` server.js this way. 
From then I didn't get any memory error both local & in staging. Any idea where am I going wrong when deployed in servers.

Note - when requested for other data like small data it was fine.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your apache2 webserver. You should check the maximum request body and timeout limits set in your config file.

Comment: The above is a good start.  But, a minimum of four mins seems a long time to wait for something back from the server.  I had a similar case where the amount of data to return could also take several minutes.   Because of this gap, I decided to the 'stream' the data from the backend in chunks, this ensures 'frequent chatter' between client and server and stopped the timeouts.  Have a look a node streams, transformations and pipes.